# SQL Server: How to show list of manager name separated by comma

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have to show employee name and his manager name hierarchy separated by comma.
if ram is top manager and ram is sam manager and sam is rahim manager then i would like to have output like

### Desired output

```
EMP Name    Manager's Name
---------   ---------------
Rahim       Sam,Ram
Sam         Ram
Ram         No manager
```

i got script which show the employee and his manager name. here is script

```
;WITH EmployeeCTE AS
(
    Select ID,Name,MgrID, 0 as level FROM @Employee
    WHERE ID=3
    UNION ALL
    Select r.ID,r.Name,r.MgrID, level+1 as level 
    FROM @Employee r
    JOIN EmployeeCTE p on r.ID = p.MgrID
)
Select e1.Name
      ,ISNULL(e2.Name,'Top BOSS') as [Manager Name]
      ,row_number() over (order by e1.level  desc) as [Level]
 from EmployeeCTE e1 
 left join EmployeeCTE e2 on e1.MgrID=e2.ID
```

### Output

```
Name    Manager Name    Level
Simon   Top BOSS        1
Katie   Simon           2
John    Katie           3
```

i also know how to show comma separated list. here is one sample script.

```
SELECT
    PNAME,
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + Mname
            FROM Myproducts M
            WHERE M.PNAME = P.PNAME
            ORDER BY Mname
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) AS Models
FROM
    Myproducts p
    GROUP BY PNAME
```

now some tell me how could i merge two script to get the desired output. thanks

Comment: So what is the original table?

Comment: employee table has EmpID,EmpName and MgrID. based on this structure how could i get desired output.....any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a table structure of

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE(
  ID    INT,
  Name  VARCHAR(10),
  MgrID INT)

INSERT INTO @Employee
VALUES      (1,'Ram',NULL),
            (2,'Sam',1),
            (3,'Rahim',2);
```

You can use

```
WITH EmployeeCTE
     AS (SELECT ID,
                Name,
                MgrID,
                0                                   AS level,
                CAST('No manager' AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS [Managers Name]
         FROM   @Employee
         WHERE  MgrID IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT r.ID,
                r.Name,
                r.MgrID,
                level + 1 AS level,
                CAST(P.Name + CASE
                                WHEN level > 0
                                  THEN ',' + [Managers Name]
                                ELSE ''
                              END AS VARCHAR(8000))
         FROM   @Employee r
                JOIN EmployeeCTE p
                  ON r.MgrID = p.ID)
SELECT *
FROM   EmployeeCTE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #EMP (
    EmpID INT
    , ManagerID INT
    , Name NVARCHAR(50) NULL
);

INSERT INTO #EMP (EmpID, ManagerID, Name)
VALUES
( 1, NULL, 'John')
, (2, 1, 'Katie')
, (3, 2, 'Simon');

SELECT *
FROM
    #EMP;

WITH a AS (
    SELECT 
        EmpID
        , Name
        , ManagerID
        , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),'') AS ManagerChain
    FROM
        #Emp
    WHERE
        ManagerID IS NULL

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        e.EmpID
        , e.Name
        , e.ManagerID
        , CASE 
            WHEN a.ManagerChain ='' THEN a.Name
            ELSE CONCAT(a.Name, CONCAT(',',a.ManagerChain))
        END
    FROM
        #Emp e
        JOIN a ON e.ManagerID = a.EmpID
)
SELECT
    a.Name
    , IIF(a.ManagerChain='','No Manager',a.ManagerChain) AS ManagerChain
FROM
    a;

DROP TABLE #EMP;
```